# ufw delete all rules

Tags: command-line, firewall, ufw

I'm trying to understand and build my own firewall for the first time.

I'm very new to this kind of things.

I came up to `ufw` and added some rules to test it.

Is there any way of deleting all the rules at once with a single command?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to turn off UFW completely and delete all the rules, you can use "reset" command:

```
ufw reset
```

Afterwards you can start it again (fresh clean) using:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

More info can be found in [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-on-ubuntu-15-04/) and the [official documents](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html)

Comment: This leaves a bunch of ufw chains in the iptables configuration. Do you know of a way to delete them as well?

Comment: Reset deletes *user* rules, but puts default rules in place, which is to deny all connections.