# Ubuntu server UFW issues

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I was sending requests to my server using postman. Then, something went wrong and all of my requests were blocked. Now, I can't send requests or even access the server using the IP address unless I use a VPN.

I am a student learning and I am pretty lost — I don't know where to start. I searched for hours on how to reset UFW and disable and enable and even adding new rules didn't work. Below is the output from the UFW iptables. I'm sending requests through postman to the server IP.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 21 packets, 2312 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4739  371K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4739  371K ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   21  2312 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   21  2312 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   21  2312 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   21  2312 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4071 6364K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4071 6364K ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   22  1466 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   22  1466 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   22  1466 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   22  1466 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   21  2312 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  444  125K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4255  243K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    5  1099 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    5  1099 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
   35  3048 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
   35  3048 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  444  125K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3605 6238K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   22  1466 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    5  1099 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   35  3048 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   11   660 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
   11   806 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7   380 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    6   316 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    1    40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 /* 'dapp_Apache' */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/889798/ufw-delete-all-rules

Comment: capitals in a heading can seem rant-like and detract from an otherwise valid question.

Comment: @raj noo it didnt i tried it and still cant send requests. i can only using a vpn still.

Comment: @24601 i will edit it out sorry im new .

Comment: I already did it for you.

Comment: @24601 Highly Appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ufw delete all rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889798/ufw-delete-all-rules)

Comment: @zx485 sadly no.